# open command could not be found

Tags: macos, command-line

Where can I find 'open' command?(OS X 10.9.3)
I think there may be some issues in my environment or I may remove this tool by mistake.

```
➜  ~  open
zsh: command not found: open
➜  ~  which open
open not found
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
➜  ~  sw_vers | grep 'Version'
ProductVersion: 10.9.3
BuildVersion:   13D65
```

Thanks

Comment: "open" should be in /usr/bin, so it is in your path. did you try /usr/bin/open $file ?

Comment: I could not find "open" under /usr/bin. Is there any way to reinstall or copy this tool?